# operational error in showed in my page saying no such table found

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

MY ERROR PAGE--------->

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGhNK.png)

THIS IS MY VIEW.PY------------>
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyH4h.png)

i am currently new to django and dont know how to solve this problem please help me get pass over this error

Answer (score 1):

first, you must check if you have migrated the model changes.
You can use `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`.
Then, make sure you have defined the "reason" field correctly. It would be helpful if you posted your models.py as well.

Comment: i cleared that but now it is showing                                                               IntegrityError at /contact
NOT NULL constraint failed: home_contact.name
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact
Django Version: 5.0
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value: 
NOT NULL constraint failed: home_contact.name
Exception Location: C:\Users\jhala\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 328, in execute
Raised during: home.views.contact
Python Executable: C:\Users\jhala\anaconda3\python.exe